# Eloquent Relationship without defining foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel

I have some query related to Eloquent Relationships in Laravel.

If I didn't specify a foreign key when using any relationship defined by laravel so laravel makes it work by assuming the foreign key based upon the parent model name as written in laravel 8 documentation.

So what I want to ask is that if laravel is only assuming means laravel will make the relationship work but data consistency will not be maintained by laravel as what foreign key does? Am I right?

And if I am right then the solution will be to explicitly define the foreign key in migration file when using relationships?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you're mixing two things, the database's DDL/schema and the ORM/database abstraction layer:

- **The database's DDL/schema** defines, how the database *itself* is structured and works. In Laravel, this can be controlled via [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations).
- **The ORM/database abstraction layer** normally doesn't alter the schema, it just does [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) (which is [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) not [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)). In Laravel, this can be done with either the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), which is an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

That means, the former *creates* the foreign key constraints, the latter only *assumes* a column name to put in the SQL query it creates